# modify script variable from a Closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to modify a script variable from inside a closure in a function. The problem can be distilled down to this:

```
@groovy.transform.Field int myField = 0

incrementField()
assert myField == 1

def incrementField() {
    1.times { myField++ }
}
```

I think the problem has something to do with [closure delegates](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy), but I cannot quite wrap my head around the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is caused by [`groovy.lang.Script`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) class and the fact that it overrides following methods:

- [`Object getProperty(String property)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)
- [`void setProperty(String property, Object newValue)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java)

Closure you have shown in the example uses `delegate` set to a script object and that's why both overridden methods get executed when you try to access or modify field defined in a script.

Now let's see what happens when your example reaches closure

```
{ myField++ }
```

Firstly, `getProperty("myField")` is called to return a value associated with this property. This method is implemented as:

```
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    try {
        return binding.getVariable(property);
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    }
}
```

> *Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54*

`binding` object contains only one variable in the beginning - closure's `args` array. If we take a look at implementation of `binding.getVariable(property)` method we will see:

```
public Object getVariable(String name) {
    if (variables == null)
        throw new MissingPropertyException(name, this.getClass());

    Object result = variables.get(name);

    if (result == null && !variables.containsKey(name)) {
        throw new MissingPropertyException(name, this.getClass());
    }

    return result;
}
```

> *Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Binding.java#L56*

In our case `MissingPropertyException` is being thrown, so `Script.getProperty(property)` method returns a value of field `myField` defined in our Groovy script - `0`. Then Groovy increments this value by 1 and tries to set this new value to a field `myField`. In this case `Script.setProperty(property, value)` is being called:

```
public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
    if ("binding".equals(property))
        setBinding((Binding) newValue);
    else if("metaClass".equals(property))
        setMetaClass((MetaClass)newValue);
    else
        binding.setVariable(property, newValue);
}
```

> *Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L62*

As you can see it sets this new value using `bindings` object. If we display `binding.variables` we will see that now this internal map contains two entries: `args -> [:]` and `myField -> 1`. It explains why assertion in your script always fails. Body of the closure you have defined never reaches `myField` field from the script class.

#### Workaround

If you are not satisfied with the fact that `Script` class overrides `setProperty(property, value)` method you can always override it by hand in your script and use same implementation as `GroovyObjectSupport.setProperty(property, value)`. Simply add below method to your Groovy script:

```
@Override
void setProperty(String property, Object newValue) {
    getMetaClass().setProperty(this, property, newValue)
}
```

Now closure defined in `incrementField` will set a new value to a class field instead of to a `bindings` object. Of course it may cause some weird side effects, you have to be aware of that. I hope it helps.

Comment: A colleague suggested the answer that I posted, but yours is a much cleaner solution. Very excellent explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Found a possible solution, using closure delegate:

```
@groovy.transform.Field def stuff = [
    myField : 0
]

incrementField()
assert stuff.myField == 1

def incrementField() {
    def body = { myField++ }
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = stuff
    1.times body
}
```