# Changing a @Field annotated variable in Jenkins after declaration?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, scope, annotations

I'm currently working on a Jenkins script that loads another Jenkins script and tries to use it as an object. Suppose my code looks like this:

Under the main Jenkins script:

```
node() {
    a = load ("path/to/file")
    println("Printing ${a.aVar}") //This prints "a"
    a.changeAVar("b")
    println("Printing ${a.aVar}") //This prints "b"
    println("Printing ${aVar}") //This should fail
}
```

Under path/to/file:

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field def aVar = "a"

def changeAVar(newAVar){
    //CODE TO CHANGE aVar = newAVar
}

return this
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to change aVar to newAVar without making aVar a global. I've tried the following:

1. aVar = newAVar turns aVar into a global
2. @Field aVar = newAVar just doesn't work since @Field needs to be in the script body.
3. def aVar = newAVar quite obviously doesn't work since aVar turns into a local variable
4. this.aVar = newAVar also turns aVar into a global for some reason
5. Even trying to change aVar outside of the script with a.aVar = "b" just wrangles it into a global

(On the other hand, if you turn aVar into a list and add to it instead of replacing it, it works just as expected)

Is it possible to reassign @Field variables after their initialization? If not, how do people usually resolve this sort of issue? (I was thinking about wrapping the sub-script in a class that I could initialize, but I feel like that's more trouble than it's worth and less intuitive)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried "aVar = newAVar" or "this.aVar = newAVar"?  If field transform is processed correctly by "load" you should be able to access it from methods just like a traditional instance field.

Comment: Those were the first two things I tried; both of them results in the "//This should fail" line executing unfortunately :(

(You can indeed access them, but the main script can also access them, which intuition suggests shouldn't happen)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "load" method's documentation?  I think it is doing something that is contrary to our intuition about Groovy scripts and the `@Field` AST transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer courtesy of [modify script variable from a Closure in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494862/modify-script-variable-from-a-closure-in-groovy); was so focused on Jenkins being the culprit that I never bothered to try out the script in Groovy.

Replacing changeAVar with

```
getMetaClass().setProperty(this, "aVar", newAVar)
```

works perfectly.

Demonstration:

```
node() {
    a = load ("path/to/file")
    println("Printing ${a.aVar.toString()}") //This prints "[]"
    a.changeAVar("b")
    println("Printing ${a.aVar.toString()}") //This prints "[b]"
    a.changeAVar2("c")
    println("Printing ${a.aVar.toString()}") //This prints "c"
    println("Printing ${aVar}") //This fails
}
```

In path/to/file:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def aVar = []

def changeAVar(newAVar){
    aVar.add(newAVar)
}

def changeAVar2(newAVar){
    getMetaClass().setProperty(this, "aVar", newAVar)
}

return this
```